# Xamarin: Android WebView is loading part of the screen

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, hybrid

I am trying to load a login webpage on HybridWebview from the sample code.

The page somehow only display part of the html shown: [image]

The code i have is:

```
const string JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";
    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                webView.SetY(500);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true; 
                webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true; 
                webView.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            Control.LoadUrl(Element.Uri);
        }
    }
```

The blue background is the background of the webview. I lower the display down to see whether the rest of the screen of hidden at the top.

Comment: Did you download the demo from https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView/ ? I think it is the issue of the html file .

Comment: Yes but not even show

Comment: Do you still face the issue if you remove the line
webView.SetY(500);